# Are democracy strongly linked to monogamy?

Tags: democracy, law, marriage

Turkey practices monogamy even though they are muslims.

> *Far from being laws to protect women, anti polygamy statutes may
>   really do more to protect men*
>
> Matt Ridley - The Red Queen

Matt argues that monogamy comes from democracy. As athens become democracy, the first thing they vote for is.

Are there any evidence suggesting this?

Did athen practice polygamy before democracy? Are there any correlation between democracy and monogamy?

Comment: Is there a good citation that this was the first thing Athens voted on?

Comment: The Republican party in America was founded on ending the twin evils of slavery and polygamy

Comment: Can anyone verify that the Matt quotes are true?

Answer (score 5):

**Correlation does not imply causation.**

Most modern states have monogamy.

Even more "most" modern democratic states have monogamy as a result of direct influence of Christianity (Christian Europe or its former colonies).

So, there's a definite correlation, but due to having a clear historical explanation, it offers no need to seek causality.

---

Having said that, the causality may very well be there as well, but it would be extremely hard to prove due to dearth of data points and ability to construct independent variables. One can of course spin theories.

- A popular belief (seemingly expressed even in the question) is the theory that, in non-monogamy with equal demographic sex distribution, the non-paired males, if given vote, would of course vote to prohibit nonmonogamy, as it would raise their chances of obtaining female mate.
- However, this gets trickier if you go for modern democracy where franchise is (unlike the case with Athens or pre-1900 USA) extended to women as well - since women generally are considered to have a preference for hypergamy which may correlate strongly with nonmonogamy. This is politically sensitive enough that not a lot of decent research is done on the topic.

Comment: *since women generally are considered to have a preference for hypergamy which may correlate strongly with nonmonogamy* So basically, you're saying most girls are just willing to go out with many guys at the same time? Source please?

Comment: @Bregalad - no, that's not at all what hypergamy means. Google is your friend.

Comment: Oh sorry, for some reason for me "hyper-" meant "big quantity", sorry for that.

Comment: @Bregalad - hyper means above, not many, in Greek, AFAIK

Comment: I still fail to see how this correlate to nomonogamy. Maybe (probably) they just want a rich high social class guy to take care of them, but don't want him to take care of other girls as well.

Comment: @Bregalad - there's research that shows that many women prefer to share a higher-status man with other women, than exclusively having a lower-status one.

Comment: Where's the research?

Comment: What's the correlation with Christianity?

Comment: @DA. - a large chunk - if not most - modern democracies are either Christian states, or former colonies of such. Both of the these categories would have no polygamy.

Comment: @DVK I mean, what's the link between Christianity being the primary reason for Monogamy? Seems the connection isn't a strong one: https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/darwin-eternity/201109/why-we-think-monogamy-is-normal

Comment: @DA. - both of the poly-friendly cultures I'm aware of (Jews and Mormons) were forced to abandon polygamy under pressure of surrounding Christians

Comment: Is that a direct connection to Christianity, or did those that oppose just happen to be Christians? In terms of Mormons, that's Christianity arguing both sides, for example. I'm not convinced the "As a direct result of Christianity" is a valid statement. It may be, but what information I find seems to not back that up strongly.

Comment: @DA. - Christianity since pretty early on prohibited polygamy. I'm not theologically informed enough to know why. But yes, both jews and mormons dropped polygamy because Christians forced them to, to conform (in Jews' case it was more like voluntary preemption to avoid being forced to)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25707/discussion-between-da-and-dvk).

Comment: @user4012 it's important to remember that the Republican party in America was founded on ending the twin evils of polygamy and slavery.