# What purpose do anti-Polygamy laws serve?

Tags: law, marriage, civil-union

Question title says it all really. Polygamy is illegal in most US states, here in Britain and also no doubt many countries elsewhere, but why? What are the political motivators for this, especially in a country which has a separation of church and state?

Comment: Are you talking about the church marrying people, or the state doing it? Because in most countries the church can marry whomever they want for whatever reason they want, but the legal ones are restricted because they come with legal rights and benefits that could be abused and/or aren't designed for more than 2 people.

Comment: @Erik the state

Comment: I think we may already have questions from sociological point of view on this?

Comment: Because in case of polygamy, majority of men will not be able to have any partners at all. This will probably cause some disappointment which will end up with an attempt to somehow get a partner which will end up with a violence. If you tell that every person can be married to at max 1 person, you ensure that majority of people will have a partner (no matter how unsuccessful they are)

Comment: Just thought I should note the difference between polygamy, where you keep multiple wives in one house/family, and bigamy, where you either have wives in separate houses ignorant of each other or else marry someone without properly divorcing an earlier spouse. See Wikipedia for definitions. Most western countries prohibit both, although the iniquities of bigamy are probably more obvious (abandonment/financial support, inheritance, etc).

Comment: @SalvadorDali: No, that does not follow. Polygamy would also allow a woman marrying multiple men, so the gender ratio of "available" people would not change.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: Note that "polygamy" by definition applies to _both genders_. Only men being allowed multiple wives is "polygyny", while the reverse is "polyandry".

Comment: @sleske no, this does follow. Just because polygamy also allow for a woman to marry  multiple men, this does not mean that the both cases happen equally likely. And based on historical data, it is way more likely for for a man to marry multiple women than other way around.

If you want to show people the meaning of the words, you can also include that polygamy is not just about humans. It is the general concept.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: Ok, with that assumption it makes sense. So what you mean is "in case of polygamy, majority of men will not be able to have any partners at all, because many men will have multiple wives, while few women will take multiple husbands".

Comment: @sleske, this is not an assumption, this is statistics. I meant exactly what I wrote. In my opinion that was pretty obvious and does not need additional explanation.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: Well, I respectfully disagree, and I think extrapolating historical data (while often valid) is a form of assumption. Let's leave it at that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some muslim countries ban polygamy?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/20521/why-do-some-muslim-countries-ban-polygamy)

Comment: One thing I'm not seeing in any answers is that for much of human history, Marriage was more about economics.   Love had very little to do with it.   As such, some of the more secular reasons for anti-polygamy laws may stem from this decision.   It's not uncommon to hear stories of people who were discovered to have two separate families that did not know about each other, which may be part of a fraud scheme of some type.

Comment: Why marry officially at all if not for tax reasons. Answer probably has to do with money. and it should maybe be mentioned that adultery (the little brother of polygamy) is much more legal than polygamy.

Answer (score 30):

The main **current** purpose those laws serve is to placate a vast majority of the citizenry who object to polygamy (to the point of, [about 100+ years ago, trying to physically destroy Mormons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Mormonism#History)).

Ironically, this is as fully bipartisan issue as they come:

- progressive feminists see [polygyny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygyny) (which is what most polyamorous relationships seem to be in history) as the ultimate expression of evil patriarchy <sub>(it's beyond the scope of the answer whether they are right or not)</sub>. *Examples: [one](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/jul/09/polygamy-uk-sharia-law-home-office-review), [two](https://www.jstor.org/stable/26505536), [three](https://www.nytimes.com/roomfordebate/2013/12/17/should-plural-marriage-be-legal/polygamy-is-bad-for-women), [four](https://digitalcommons.pepperdine.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1056&context=globaltides), [five](https://www.nationalreview.com/2017/05/polyamory-polygamy-same-practice-now-presented-edgy-fresh/)*.
- right wing social conservatives see it as contradictory to mainline Christianity and New Testament rules (conveniently ignoring the whole King David, and especially king Solomon, precedents from Old Testament :) and generally a sexually deviant thing <sub>(it's beyond the scope of the answer whether they are right or not)</sub>. *Examples: [one](https://www.gotquestions.org/polygamy.html), [two](https://nealhardin.com/polygamy-in-the-bible/).*
- just to make this political bed-meeting weirder (and poly? :), the less-successful (or less full of themselves) people in MRA/etc... scene also object to polygyny, as it enables women to indulge in hypergamy even easier <sub>(it's beyond the scope of the answer whether they are right or not)</sub>. The only time they see eye to eye with hard-core third wave feminists, I suppose. But stranger things happened. *Examples: [one](https://heartiste.org/2010/11/18/polyamory-is-disguised-polygamy/)*

---

#### Polling

Let's get down to the numbers. Even in these, extremely sexually liberal times, with polygamy being "morally acceptable" # as high as it's ever been in USA, ***only*** 17% population supports it, according to [Gallup 2017 poll](http://news.gallup.com/poll/210542/americans-hold-record-liberal-views-moral-issues.aspx). That's up from only 7% in 2003.

If that seems "high" - compare it to 63%<sup>[1]</sup> supporting gay/lesbian sexual relations<sup>[2]</sup>.

---

#### Rationale

However, an argument can be (and is) made that those laws are in fact socially a good thing, in both theoretical and practical way:

**In theory**, in a society with permitted polygamy, there's a high chance that a large portion of less-successful (straight) males would end up with no female partnership. This is a recipe for social disorder if there ever was one - it's well known from sociological and psychological research that males in long term relationships are far less likely to engage in risky, asocial, or criminal behavior; and are more likely to be more socially productive. Or, like, "not engage in mass violence and rioting", which probably should be considered a good thing, eh?

In practice, there is tons of research that polygamy has bad outcomes, although in all honesty, I haven't vetted ANY of the following links and don't know how solid (or biased) the research is. YMMV, PATYR.

- [The Perils of Polygamy](http://www.thepublicdiscourse.com/2012/05/5338/) has some in depth discussion (note: it seems to be a socially conservative think tank, so they clearly have an axe to grind).
- [The pros and cons of polygamy](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/darwin-eternity/201507/the-pros-and-cons-polygamy) from Psychology Today. They often have progressive bent in my limited experience (as in, publish articles how conservatism is a mental disorder, in full seriousness) so probably also have a different axe to grind.
- [Slate](http://www.slate.com/articles/double_x/doublex/2012/01/the_problem_with_polygamy.html) lists a study highlighting problems. Again, progressive axe grinding is likely.
- [The Atlantic had an article critical of polygamy from societal standpoint](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2006/04/one-man-many-wives-big-problems/304829/), largely drawing from non-poly-related study of male-surplus Asian societies in 2004 book "Bare Branches: Security Implications of Asia's Surplus Male Population" by Valerie M. Hudson and Andrea M. den Boer.

---

Having said that, the above reasoning and arguments ***are NOT the purpose*** of anti-poly laws, although they may be used by defenders of such laws. The purpose stated above is the only one - to placate the majority of population that for one reason or another supports such laws.

---

<sub>[1] and if that 63% people who find homosexual relations morally acceptable seems low - that's only 6% less than 69% who find **sex outside marriage** morally acceptable. As in, only 6% more people don't accept homosexuality than "living in sin"</sub>

<sub>[2] Then again, one has to wonder at how much social acceptability bias affected that poll, since a staggeringly low 9% considers extramarital affairs "morally acceptable", compared to between 20 and 70% estimates of people actually cheating.</sub>

Comment: Good answer, thanks. However, one thing is missing. Do you have statistics on the amount of the population that object to polygamy?

Comment: Given that polyamory exists even without legal marriage options, it seems the dangers of it aren't very high. Most polyamorous people seem quite happy with it.

Comment: @Charlie - added polling.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning the inherent additional complexity of next-of-kin relationships?  If someone was in a coma and had two spouses, what if they disagreed about medical decisions?  Then again, that may not actually be so different from a child where the parents disagree...

Comment: @Bobson - correct. And it seems there's plenty of disagreements already (*source: watching first 9 seasons of "E.R."*). Also, advanced medical directives/living wills seem like a good thing.

Comment: Brilliant sideline with the Mormons, and the "people's support for it (or against  poly-) is also what I see strongest, but in the first list the 3rd bullet is beyond my understanding: what is "MRA"? Then there is equal opportunity to mate, inheritance complications, and if males are forbidden to poly, so are females?

Comment: @LangLangC MRA is [men's rights activism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men%27s_rights_movement), but that covers a lot of topics. The hypergamy thing is more associated with the so-called ["manosphere"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manosphere), which has overlap with MRA but is a distinct thing.

Comment: @LangLangC - this is anecdotal based on my observations, but the main political/ideological opposition to poly is from feminists, who (due to their misguided worldview of "a few top men is the same things as all men") consider it a Bad Thing, ignoring the fact that poly* benefits many women and very very few men in reality, with most men losing compared to status quo. However, the manosphere (I'm OK with eyeballfrog's clarification though things are more nuanced than that) **does** know that fact; and therefore also opposes poly* as "bad for men".

Comment: What does **YMMV, PATYR** means ? Googling it didn't help.

Comment: @Evargalo - they are independent abbreviations. https://www.google.com/search?q=ymmv . *ATYR means do something at your own risk.

Comment: @user4012 Women benefiting from polygyny is questionable. Societies with widespread polygyny tend not to be the kind of societies that respect women, and the mechanism is rather obvious. Feminists see this and know to oppose it, even if their stated reasons are sometimes off base.

Comment: @eyeballfrog - correllation != causation. Most known societies with widespread poligyny that can be studied had socioeconomic conditions that made it inevitable to be, to loosely steal a term from feminists, "patriarchical". However, there's nothing inherent in poligyny that would *cause* women to be unequal; as modern Western Poly* groups (most of which seem to be politically progressive overall due to deep LGBT ties if no other reason) demonstrate.

Comment: ... and no, the mechanism is not obvious at all. If **a woman has a choice** between pairing up with higher status male as one of several mates, and with a lower status male as a single mate, (as opposed to historical case where a family or circumstances made the choice for her for socioeconomic reasons), there's nothing about that choice to make her less respected. The only people who are systematically worse off in Poly* enabled society are lower status/lower attraction males.

Comment: "Now about that time Herod the king stretched forth his hands to vex certain of the church.
And he killed James the brother of John with the sword.
And because he saw it pleased the Jews, he proceeded further to take Peter also." Acts 12:1-3

Comment: Much of this answer is about polygyny specifically, and doesn't really generalise to polygamy in general (which makes it comes across as somewhat dishonest). If men can have multiple partners, there may be more unhappy single males. But if women can have multiple partners, it seems like there'd be *fewer* unhappy single males. The two fully balance each other out on paper, and they may even help reduce unhappy single people even further (but what would happen in practice depends on way too many factors to jump to conclusions about).

Comment: @NotThatGuy - for evolutionary psychology reasons that are too complicated to explain in a space of a single comment, a vast majority of normal males aren't into sharing their female partner (women are more open to sharing a high quality partner though). Additionally, if you look at reality of gender mate selection, you'd STILL end up with a few "top" males having several females and majority of the males having none. Look at the research on online dating sites, it's pretty illuminating on what females choose when they have full freedom and unlimited resources to do so.

Comment: @user4012 Men not being into non-exclusive partners seems contrary to your own argument, because you're trying to say they'd be deeply unhappy alone, while also trying to say they'd not be so unhappy as to opt for a non-exclusive partner (never mind that this arguably has a lot more to do with gender stereotypes than "evolutionary psychology"). And online dating might warp partner expectations in ways that are deeply destructive to individuals and society, but that doesn't have much to do with polygamy.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure someone will write a better answer but here are couple points:

1. **Culture**: Some countries just don't have a culture of polygamy. There is also an issue of who gets to marry multiple times and who doesn't, because in some places you can only do so if you are of a certain gender. It just opens a whole realm of new debates.
2. **Administrative complexity**: From an administrative perspective, keeping track of marriages is easier when people only practice serial monogamy. The interweb of marriages and the legal responsibilities that follow could become quite complex very quickly.
3. **Inheritance**: This might be the most critical reason as monogamy was originally introduced to enforce economic security. Using legally-recognized marriage as marker for which child deserves inheritance and which doesn't is an important way to keep wealth within the family. This applies to ancient monarchies as much as to real-estate owners. I would assume legalizing polygamy would create an entire industry of lawyers dedicated to sort out these issues.

Comment: The 3. point is not (or no longer) valid in many countries, at least as far as children are concerned. Children are often entitled to inherit from their parents, regardless of their parents marriage status.

Comment: to further elaborate on what @Hulk said inheritance can always be specified in a will.  An individual can have whoever they choose inherit regardless of marriage.  This may be a historical reason why monogamy originally existed (...maybe, not sure it's not a post-hoc explanation even historically), but it seems pretty flimsy as a modern criticism given how easy it is to ensure inheritance happens in whatever manner you want if it's something that matters to you.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, anti-polygamy laws serve to "protect" traditional marriage (at least, traditional in the eyes of the Christian West) the same way that laws against same-sex marriage were supposed to.  Note that these laws apply only to the *legal* institution of marriage, not the religious institution.

Unlike prohibitions against same-sex marriage, I doubt that prohibitions against polygamous marriage will be overturned anytime soon for the following reasons:

1. Same-sex marriages don't introduce the legal headaches for custody, power of attorney, property rights, inheritance, etc., that polygamous marriages would.  How would you apportion assets in a poly divorce when a partner leaves?  When multiple partners leave?  How about parental rights?
2. Right now, polygamy (at least in the US) is most closely associated with some groups that are, let's face it, pretty far out on the fringe socially and politically, and it's not the *polygamy* that makes them so fringey.
3. There are arguments that poly marriages (especially polygyny, multiple wives for a single husband) truly are bad arrangements in a number of objectively measurable ways, although I don't know how solid those arguments are.  But they're not the silly slippery slope arguments employed against allowing same-sex marriage ("why, next thing you know, people will be marrying their *pets*").

Comment: 3) is only true because of the strong impression of looking at the fringe groups in 2) for how it works. There are many happily-together poly couples, you just don't see/hear much about them because being poly gets a bad rep.

Comment: While the whole protecting traditional marriage thing is true I think your stressing it to much. Anti poly sentiment is not nearly as closely linked to high religiosity as gay marriage opposition was.  There are many who support gay marriage who are anti poly and many agnostics as well.  Heavy religious folks are more likely to be anit-poly, but the opposition to poly isn't nearly as driven by religion as anti-gay marriage was.  Also while I have no issue with first two #3 needs to be justified or removed.  "Trust me there are good reasons I just won't tell you" is never a winning argument.

Comment: @dsollen: My point with #3 is that opponents to poly marriage have put forward arguments that are not *obviously* silly on their face; I'm not saying I agree or disagree with those arguments, only that they merit real consideration and shouldn't be dismissed out of hand. Personally I don't care beyond the issues in point #1, and that's for lawyers to figure out.  It would result in *extensive* changes to state family law, an area that's already fraught.  That's the main reason I don't see anyone taking up this particular banner.

Answer (score 1):

There are two very major issues with the polygamy:

- For single woman - multiple men case, it will be children that are not genetically related at all to (another) father in the family. Yet they benefit from the work, achievements, inheritance from this (second) father. Not all men enjoy this and many would insist that the woman should be only for him. It may be some pre-programmed behavior there, as many animals live in groups led by dominant male that does not let other males nearby.
- For single man - multiple woman case, seems more important that this would create a fraction of young men unable to create a family and potentially ready for everything to achieve this goal. Vikings [went as far as](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/viking-sex-tourists-lived-happily-ever-after-with-britons-5370306.html) sailing to the coasts of England and stealing girls there, DNA analysis confirm. This is only great if you recruit these men into army and send on someones head. Otherwise they will arrange a bloody coup sooner or later.
- In any case, single marriage and 50:50 % gender ratio provides reasonable guarantees that everyone seeking a partner will find one. Without these constraints, it is less likely.

The state has interest for majority of people creating families and having children, because these can provide care and support for they aged parents. While this can also be provided by various pension funds, support from children is the most natural and may be still required.

Comment: The Vikings didn’t have a shortage of women, as higher child mortality among boys and constant warfare ensured there were more women than men in every adult age bracket up until the 20th century.

Comment: I feel your argument falls apart with the presumption that the state wants majority of people to create families and have children as that is far from a given.  China clearly didn't want that when they had the 1 child policy for example.  I think your first argument is poorly phrased as well.  step parents don't have an issue with providing for their step children after all.  I agree not all men would want that, but at most you explained why it may be a less commonly chosen option, not why it shouldn't be an option for those that want it.

Comment: As to your Vikings claim as @JonathanReez said they had no shortage of females.  In fact any culture with extensive travel as Vikings is expected to have DNA from multiple regions as a result of travel.  Even the first sentence of the article you linked says they don't know that this was a result of kidnap or rape vs willing travel and integration.

Comment: @dsollen I'm not saying the Vikings didn't reproduce while abroad. What I'm saying is that they didn't *need* to go abroad to reproduce.

Comment: @dsollen Be fruitful and multiply.  Have you forgotten it?

Comment: @JonathanReez You know I was agreeing with your argument right?  My point was that there is no evidence the DNA evidence OP mentioned didn't come from sources other then the implied kidnapping and rape.  Not that it matters, the mere fact that they weren't compelled to travel due to lack of available females as you said is enough to invalidate the argument, but I just don't like someone claiming something was proven by a study when the study itself explicitly says they did not prove that.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo what if I would rather be vegetableful and divide?  Seriously though how does a random bible quote matter?  I'd like to claim that the first amendment means it doesn't apply to government laws, but I'd be kidding myself.  Regardless though most religious folks don't take that to mean they have to pop out kids non stop.  We have seen a multitude of Christian nations who actually wanted to decrease pop growth.  In neither country mentioned by OP have I ever heard it stated by those nations that they were striving for, or felt they needed, more kids people popping out babies.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Okay people on SE need to stop making unknowingly ironic statements when I know it would derail the conversation to point it out :P.  Ignoring the fact that Christians hardly conquered 'nearly everything' you have not explained why the country should care *now* about birth rate, since you think their disbanding their army. considering neither country has claimed to want more children born and all the policies they are *not* enacting that could increase birth rates why do you presume this one policy would exist solely to encourage it?  Why force insurance to cover BC?

Answer (score 1):

I fully back user4012 answer, the majority of the motives for outlawing polygamous relationships is not about rational arguments but tradition, religion, and 'morality' that is defined as deviation from the norm being bad.  IE most people can't give you a hard and clear utilitarian argument for why they think it's wrong, it just feels wrong or it's 'immoral' without a good explanation for why it's immoral.

That being said there are two fairly rational arguments that can be made, even if this is not the real motive in most cases.

**It makes marriage law harder if legal so polygamous folks should just do it on their own without demanding marriage.**

The contractual relationship that is marriage is already extremely complex.  Trying to extend these sort of laws to handle numerous individuals in a way that does not unfairly favor a specific demographic (see below) is not all that easy.  What does a divorce mean if one person out of four leaves a marriage, how are assets divided?  What if that one leaving was the primary producer of wealth, how do you handle alimony who keeps the house?  How is custody handled and does the degree of biological connection to the child matter?  Can a kid end up bouncing between five homes in a week because the entire marriage broke up and everyone wanted equal custody?

Furthermore marriage offers tax benefits (sort of, it's actually more complicated).  How do taxes work for three people filing jointly?  Currently our tax law just doesn't support that.  And this isn't limited to taxes.  Does my health insurance cover my entire family if I'm married to five other people and we all have kids together?  Won't that bankrupt my insurance company, or at minimum result in other insurance holders subsidizing my families insurance?

It's just easier legally to only support two person marriage and let the rest have a romantic and/or sexual relationship outside the strict legal definition of marriage.

All of this would be a real hassle to sort out, but that doesn't make it impossible.  Sure you can make laws and smarter tax/insurance policies and sort this all out in time.  You could very well argue that this is ultimately an argument from laziness, and well it is.

But the real world is not rational or perfect.  To be frank arguments from laziness *work*.  Most people don't care about or want a polygamous relationship.  Some of them may be theoretically open to supporting others having them if they want; but when you point out the cost and effort of making it legally recognized well allot of them are going to question rather it's worth all that effort to make a minority happy.  I'm not saying rather or not that argument is morally right, but it is a real argument that would happen.

Still this is the lesser argument, the real argument is...

**It usually results in a small number of powerful males having all the power**

Here we have to discuss polygamy in theory vs practice.  Polygamy in theory is a thing a number of people might support, love whoever you want to love.  But when we look at it in historical practice it usually doesn't work out like the theory.

In the vast majority of cases where polygamy was practiced it usually ended up with a single dominate male having a number of wives forced into some degree of subservience to the male; how severe that was varied greatly.  Often polygamy was less about "these folks all love each other" and more about "this powerful man want's another women to have sex with so he's going to pressure her into being his subservient wife"

This resulted in two issues.  First the majority of males had no wives, and when 'family men' were then favored as a status symbol it would further render those who couldn't achieve wives into a lower socioeconomic class that furthered economic divides.  Since everyone answering seemed to focus on the plights of lower class males I won't focus on that aspect as I figure it's already been well addressed, and  perhaps even overstated, in other answers.

However things were not much better for the females.  Since usually a man dominated women were often forced to join a marriage less based off of actual romantic attraction and more out of necessity.  Especially the younger wives tended to lack power.  Their voices would be ignored and they had to just accept decisions made by the man and possible his first few more powerful wives.  Even if the women was unhappy and wished to leave she usually couldn't because she would end up without financial support for her or her kids, she may even risk losing custody and contact with her kids.  The net result was that she ended up dependent on staying in the marriage even if she found it extremely unpleasant.  This was rarely a good situation for the girl.

Again I stress I'm not claiming this is the case in all situations.  There have even been cases of female dominated polygamy, though putting a few powerful women in charge is hardly better then putting a few powerful males in charge.  I am only claiming that historically this has been the most common outcome.  I also want to stress I'm not claiming that's what is wanted by most arguing for polygamy currently.

See this is the problem, right now there are people out there that desire polygamous relationships because they want to share romantic (and/or sexual) relationships with more then one person.  Most of them have no desire to abuse such a marriage situation and in fact would find such a male dominated relationship as I described reprehensible.  While I can't claim to be an expert in that community from what little exposure I have the majority seem to have sincere desires to simply share love with multiple people.

However, once the laws support it others will use it.  Any system that exists will have at least some who will try to exploit it.  There is plenty of evolutionary psychology reasons to believe powerful males would love to have their own harem of women, and plenty of historical evidence that too many powerful men treated polygamous marriage as more of a harem then an actual shared loving relationship.  In a world where men already have more power then women (while we are getting better I don't think were anywhere close to an equal divide on power between the sexes) it's not unreasonable to worry if the same patter we have seen historically will occur again.

In other words regardless of the sincere desire of it's proponents who want polygamous relationships making it legally supported has a non-trivial chance of resulting in the sort of abuse we've seen in the past.  It may not be the current proponents of such marriages who are most at risk of abusing them, but it doesn't really matter how the abuse comes about, if abuse of such marriages did occur it would be a problem.

Now one could argue that now that feminism has gone a long way towards fighting for women's rights and we have laws and culture that are more even in regards to distribution of power between the sexes it would not be as easy for dominate males to rule relationships as it was in the historical polygamous marriages we have seen.  One can counter that the power dynamics are better but women still tend to be worse off and so men dominating such a relationship is a likely situation.  You could also argue it doesn't really matter rather the person dominating a polygamous marriage happens to have an 'innie' or an 'outie' when it comes to sexual organs, the real point is that these marriages tended to be dominated by one person which lead to unfair situation for the rest in the folks in the marriage.  Allot of historical polygamous relationships also involved girls forced into marriage at a young age, further ensuring they would lack power in such a relationship.  Thus one might argue modern day legal polygamous marriage is less likely to have issues with power dynamics and abuse if we restrict it to only being entered into by fully consenting mature adults. All these arguments depend allot on ones specific views and I'm not going to try to claim which are stronger arguments and which aren't; frankly I don't know myself.

In fact I'm not saying that either of the main bullet pointed arguments I've made are sufficient to refuse polygamous marriage being legal.  If I suddenly was told I'm in charge of marriage law* and have to decide what to do I'd be demanding far more historical records and studies to help determine how likely abuse of such a system really was and be comparing that to how many people expressed a desire for such relationships and felt harmed by the lack of such laws to try to better weigh the pro and cons of such a change.  Since I lack all those studies and a sufficiently through understanding of all polygamous historical records I will not even try to render a verdict or the viability of legalized polygamous marriage.

What I will say is that I think there is a sufficient potential, and historic records, of abuse that such a risk must be reasonable considered and measured before one should say that polygamous marriage must be legalized.

And again I stress in many ways these are post-hoc justification.  Most people oppose polygamous marriage not based off such utilitarian arguments and more because they think it feels wrong, 'immoral', strange, or just icky to them.

* In actuality if someone really did try to put me in charge of marriage law I would laugh in their face for putting an aromantic person in charge of marriages.
I'd then ask if they also put a child in charge of setting laws for nursing homes and a bunch of old white men in charge of women reproductive rights *cough*.  I imagine my next steps would be to scramble to try to find someone, anyone, better qualified then me to take over instead.  But failing that I'd fall back on research to make a decision on such laws as I said above.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly to use low-status men for the needs of wider society, rather than against it.
If it's socially accepted to have multiple wives, a low-status man has little incentive to be productive and not violent. If it's assumed that some guys get multiple official wives, some of them have 0 wives despite their best attempts.
That makes suicidal and violent tendencies stronger.
In a monogamous society, even if some guys have more sexual partners than other's, there's at least a moral ideal of "there's a wife for everybody, because everybody should have at most one wife".

Comment: Do you have evidence to back up this reasoning? A similar reasoning was presented in another question where [an answerer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/78299) came up with [a professor of social demography saying](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/article/3133656/china-home-30-million-men-search-bride-census-shows) *"The correlation between gender imbalance and crime rate is not strong"*. That question was about an imbalance in the population while this question is more about an artificial imbalance, though it's not clear why the reasoning would hold here when it doesn't seem to there.

Comment: Young males commit most crimes.
And you know why young men take more risks?

"Simply put, males commit much more crime than females. In UCR data, men comprise about 81 percent of all arrests for violent crime and about 63 percent of all arrests for property crime."

"Accordingly, people in the 15–24 age range account for about 40 percent of all arrests even though they comprise only about 14 percent of the population."

https://open.lib.umn.edu/socialproblems/chapter/8-3-who-commits-crime/

Answer (score -4):

To ration females to males in equal share for everyone. Prohibition of polygamy, if combined with no sex outside marriage, will ensure the poorest ugliest dumbest males will still be able to get a wife.

Why "society" bother doing that? Well, the poorest, ugliest, dumbest males can vote. Politicians want their vote.

If polygamy are allowed, guys like Donald Trump/Bradd Pitt can get 5-10k wives, and many guys will get none. That's because men, if allowed, will aim for quantity. Look at Sultans and emperors. To prevent that, the laws "ration" females in equal share for everyone.

Yes. Women are still legal to choose poor men. However, if those women can choose to share richer smarter men instead, will they? It's like employers can still legally hire Americans. But if those employers can hire cheaper immigrants instead, will they?

Men will instinctively sabotage their competitors. So marriage laws in democratic countries allow women to pick only singles.

Matt Ridley in his book Red Queen says something along, "Far from laws protecting women ... anti polygamy statues really protect men"

Here is the quote and the whole argument

https://books.google.co.id/books?id=CWza0RyG_MwC&pg=PT248&lpg=PT248&dq=%22Far+from+being+laws+to+protect+women,+anti+polygamy+statutes+may+really+do+more+to+protect+men%22&source=bl&ots=5TPxLgKY61&sig=JNa24MCNApUr-RCSvf5qmasH194&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif1sO8sJbfAhUKtY8KHWdmAo0Q6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Far%20from%20being%20laws%20to%20protect%20women%2C%20anti%20polygamy%20statutes%20may%20really%20do%20more%20to%20protect%20men%22&f=false

[image]

In democratic countries, the majority rules.

The majority of people are not alpha males.

So they choose to ban polygamy.

In general, we get free competition, if a small number of people compete for the benefit of majority.

For examples, most businesses compete with each other. The majority of people are benefited from their competition and hence force businesses to compete.

However, competing is not a good idea for profit.

If the majority is the competitor, we usually have trade restrictions.

The trade restrictions are in favor of majority.

For example, we got many trade restrictions in labor market. That's because laborers are majority compared to employers. Laborers are significant "voting bloc" so to speak.

Majority of men are poor or middle classes. So marriage laws in many democratic countries tend to kick out the rich from mating market.

For example, within marriage, alimony tend to be proportional to wealth of a man. This discourage richer men from getting married. Using money to get girls tend to be heavily discouraged. Explicit use of using money to get girls, called prostitution, is prohibited.

Like all marriage, the states heavily influence who can marry who.

In states that allow polygamy, who would stop the law makers from saying that girls can only marry guys that vote for me or embrace my religions? That means the religious leaders, or the alpha males, pretty much become pimp of all girls. Only by obeying the whim of those alpha males, usually called religion, a man can get laid.

No wonder, middle east often have war.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Read the red queen. It's pretty obvious.

Comment: I got the quote from https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8571/are-democracy-strongly-linked-to-monogamy . I can't find other sources. Can anyone check is the quote true?

Comment: I got the quotes there? Hello? Anyone can point out where this is wrong?

Comment: Presumably they disagree with the premise, especially as anti-polygamy is almost entirely a Christian phenomenon

Comment: @Orangesandlemons - "almost entirely a Christian phenomenon" - you must not have been on any feminist blogs or other sources recently.

Comment: @user4012 I was talking about the implementation of laws, but I am actually not so sure if I'm happy with my 'almost entirely' as Rome had legalised for monogamy, and are likely a major contribute to current laws. However the facts do not generally support the answer, so I'm guessing that's why the downvoters downvoted

Comment: It's hard to imagine that any western 21st century legislative body would introduce polygamy without also introducing polyandry. In that case the whole argument "not enough wifes for all men" breaks down, because multiple men can also share a wife.

Comment: @Philipp Assuming men are equally likely to accept their wife having multiple husbands as women are to accept their husband having multiple wives.

Comment: @Philipp: Just to keep our terminology straigth: As I explained in my comment to the Q, "polygamy" is the gender-independent term (at least according to the dictionaries I checked). The gender-specific terms are "polyandry" (multiple husbands, as you correctly wrote) and "polygyny" (multiple wifes). I hate it if people mix up definitions, and it confuses everyone :-).

Comment: Monogamy is in a sense, not christian phenomenon. Polygamy is illegal in Rome way before long and Christianity's precursors, Judaism, never prohibit Polygamy. Even Jesus have some parables where 10 brides are to marry a "groom". Latter, Christianity becomes Rome's official religion. So the tenets also match Roman culture.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is completely ridiculous. Why shouldn't men you believe aren't "alpha males" be allowed to marry? If a woman wants to marry such a man, who are you to stop her? "Marriage laws in many democratic countries tend to kick out the rich from mating market" - if you have any statistics to back that up, I'd love to see them, because to me that sounds completely false. Most billionaires I can think of are married. And what does polygamy have to do with the frequent Middle-Eastern conflicts? Do you seriously think they're fighting over each others' wives?

Comment: If polygamy are allowed, guys like Donald Trump will have 5-10k wives, and you will get none. That's because men, if allowed, will aim for quantity. Look at Sultans and emperors. To prevent that, the laws "ration" females in equal share for everyone.

Comment: Women are free to choose non alpha males. However, if they can choose to share richer smarter males, will they? Just like any customers can choose to buy from mom and pop biz instead of wallmart. Will they? Often not. Or employers have right to hire americans. If they are allowed to hire immigrants too, will they?

Comment: Fixed the answer to address your concern. Do you think Matt Ridley is wrong or what? He's an evolutionary psychologist you know. And I am quoting him.

Comment: It's the same way affirmative actions kick asians out of american university. Yes there are still plenty of asians in american university. It tend to balance things out. Without affirmative actions, 70% of american university will be filled with Asians. Marriage is the same. Without huge alimony and child support and anti polygamy laws, 70% of girls will pick the top 20% richest. Prohibition of non alpha males from getting married is similar in spirit with prohibition of sex outside marriage in general. Also in muslim countries, muslim women cannot marry non muslims.

Comment: Here, someone else, the alpha males (religious leaders, politicians), decide who you can marry (only singles, only co religions, bla bla bla), and who you can have sex with (not for money, no porn, not based on beauty, bla bla bla). Why they do so? Usually to gain power and support from other non alpha males (singles, co religionists, feminazis, bla bla bla)

Comment: I don't think people disagree with your quote, in fact it is found in a different form within the other answer " there's a high chance that a large portion of less-successful (straight) males would end up with no female partnership". It's all your ranting about side-issues and non-sequiturs like "No wonder, middle east often have war."

Comment: It is related. The Middle East has more war because many single males are angry that they are single. Takeshi Kanazawa writes an article about that. In the western world, you have a high chance of getting a wife. In Arab, becoming king is more important.

Comment: "Why downvotes?" Because it makes sense from game theory perspective, but makes too many people really uneasy.

Comment: Why downvote?  For starters it's at most a post-hoc justification which fails at it's own arguments.  to explain why many powerful males who would benefit by your definition have opposed polygomy?   Why should politicians care more for the males without marriage then the females that by your claim should prefer polygamy?  If all females benefit by getting a 'better' husband and 20% of males benefit by being your 'alpha male' (ps. wolves don't work that way!) then by your own arguments sounds like 60% of population should be pro polygamy right?  Their votes are greater then poor males votes.

Comment: You also seem to be mixing in a bit of MRA nonsense in this.  You mention alimony but only 7 states offer permanent alimony and it's based off of who is highest income not sex, women pay alimony to men too.  You ignore the fact that women often pay child support to males and it's not limited to marriage.  While single male with multiple women is likely you extremely exaggerate the amount and prevalence (10K wives really?  no women would stick to monogamy at all?).  You speak as if women are a thing to be divide out to each men as wives without discussing their rights, desires, or needs.

Comment: @dsollen nobody ignores female-to-male alimony payments. But because of what feminists call "gender pay gap" men are typically earning more money than women and therefore, alimony payments typically flow from male to female. Also, even if alimony is not permanent, it's still there. And also child support is awarded in proportion to male's income, not in proportion to child's needs.

Comment: @dsollen also it's not that likely that alpha males + most women will vote install polygamy. Mostly because of cultural factors.
1. Competition is not so clear. Some men compete with money, some with muscle, some with sense of humour, so every man hopes to find a niche, or at least a wife that will like him.
2. For biggest losers, you would have to exterminate them... meanwhile they can still work, pay taxes, watch porn and dream of having a girlfriend one day.
3. Alphas typically are not that vile as well. If I have enough sex with my girlfriend, I don't mind my neighbour having a wife.

Comment: Apart from the other issues, this answer doesn't make sense in countries where women can vote. The premise is that monogamy forces women to choose against their desires, which by the logic of this answer means that women would vote with the elite men - which together is a majority.

Comment: Ugly women outnumber the pretty. They also tend to vote against either porn or prostitution or sex trades.

Comment: @dsollen the law doesn't really protect women or men. The laws add transactional complexity between rich men and pretty women. So you're right sometimes women pay alimony too. So? It still make transaction complex for rich man and pretty women. I am a libertarian. Not exactly an MRA advocate. I do not care that women want money or not. I think men shouldn't have right to regulate that. I just think women should have choices to just ask for money and be mistress if that's what she wish.