# Why government don't simply make "legally recoqnized" polygamy impossible?

Tags: marriage

This question asks why anti Polygamy laws exist.

[What purpose do anti-Polygamy laws serve?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24813/what-purpose-do-anti-polygamy-laws-serve/36020#36020)

However,

Marriage require consent of 3 parties. The man, the wife, and government.

If Ann is married to Bob, then it must be registered in government database. If Ann then want to marry Charlie, then why can't government simply make that impossible?

Before marrying anyone, government can simply says, ups, you cannot marry, you are still married based on my database.

Rather than punishing polygamy, why doesn't US government simply make that impossible by not officiating marriage between people that are not single?

Why punish something you can effectively prevent people from doing in the first place easily?

Note: This question has many good answers. I was just pointing out that I was under the impressions that polygamy can only be done by mistakes. Why would anyone commit a crime with almost 100% probability of getting caught. In game theory, it's not "reasonable" (or what's term in game theory for picking a strategy that is strictly dominated no matter what).

I think anti polygamy laws is a bit similar like https://www.news.com.au/travel/travel-updates/woman-forced-to-cancel-dream-trip-to-new-york-after-accidentally-telling-the-us-shes-a-terrorist/news-story/bc496a06a6ae8891853c0df19a06d4e1 You will be in trouble for checking yes I am a terrorist but that's pretty pointless. Why would anyone do that?

Another issue is that polyamory and sugar relationship is legal in United States. So why would anyone that want to have several woman just don't involve the state.

Hence, committing "legally recognized" polygamy, in a sense of registering your second marriage is a crime with 100% chance of getting caught and with almost nothing to gain. Doesn't seem like something need criminalizing. No body would bother doing that anyway.

Also I think this is still a legitimate question. That is why I am reopening.

Comment: Why downvotes? Any reason? Government can simply prevent all polygamy by not allowing polygamist to register their marriage. Why bother making a law punishing them?

Comment: Lots of problems with this question. First, marriage isn't between the man, the wife, and the government. Marriage, as viewed by many, is between the couple and God(or in accordance to their religious traditions). This topic gets hairy, so it is sometimes beneficial to make a distinction between government marriage (civil unions) and religious marriage.  IMHO, the true answer to this question lies in what the federal government actual is and what it is trying to do vs what the laws do. Government lists aren't popular among Americans.

Comment: @DavidS: Marriage is a function of state government, not the federal government.

Comment: Okay I don't really differentiate between state and federal government. In that case, why the states don't simply make polygamy impossible? It seems that if you can easily prevent something, punishing someone from doing what you can easily prevent doesn't seem like "good intention". Also I think anti polygamy laws in US punish government marriage. Am I correct there?

Comment: "Why punish something you can effectively prevent people from doing in the first place easily?" Because they didn't want to. They wanted to regulate that on a federal level and there punishment may be the only available legal option.

Comment: That's currently how it works, so I'm not sure how to answer the question. It's not legal to be married to more than one person.  But people do illegal crap all the time. It's like asking why bank robbery is illegal by arguing that they should've just made the money impossible for you to steal in the first place.

Comment: How common is polygamy? How much would it cost to maintain such a database? Who would be responsible for its accuracy? How accurate would it be? At what stage during the process of marrying would it be tested against? What do you know about how marriage works in the US? What happens if someone moves to a different state?

Comment: First, why should it be banned in the first place?  After all, in the US (and other parts of the world) we've spent the last century or so slowly getting rid of various forms of marriage discrimination: inter-racial, same-sex, &c.  Why not polygamy?  Second is how you define "marriage": if it's a purely religious or social marriage, there's no reason for the government to know about it.

Comment: @jamesqf There is the situation of bigamy, where one of a couple "marries" another person without knowledge of their partner. Aka "the only crime that is its own punishment". And there are many situations where being married to someone has high legal significance.

Comment: Actually it makes sense. We make stealing bitcoin impossible. But, in addition to that, we criminalize it just in case people succeed. I see

Comment: @user4951 Stealing Bitcoin is impossible, yet there have been a number of high-profile thefts. (See: Mt. Gox). How much harder would it be to ensure a _government run_ database is secure?

Comment: Your point assumes that such a database already exists. Such data are often not recorded in that form.

Comment: @gnasher729: That sort of bigamy is an entirely different situation from a consensual polygamous marriage.

Answer (score 5):

If the government were to do this, it would be about as effective [as the database to prevent mentally ill people from buying guns](https://www.cnn.com/2018/02/15/politics/mental-health-gun-possession-explainer/index.html).

> When [something that puts you on the list] happens in Florida, the court or government body that made the decision on the individual's mental health is required to report that record to a state law enforcement agency or the FBI.
>
> The records would be in the National Instant Criminal Background Check System, a confidential database that houses the names and birth years of individuals ineligible to buy firearms.
>
> A licensed gun dealer is required under federal law to run potential buyers through the criminal background check system. The process usually takes around 90 seconds, and, if all the records are in the right place, would prevent a purchaser who was previously involuntarily committed or adjudicated as mentally incompetent from getting the gun.
>
> But federal law doesn't require states to make these mental health records part of background check system, and many fail to voluntarily report the records.
> And licensed gun shops aren't the only places to buy a firearm.

So having such a database would require every state to correctly submit updated records in a timely manner.  If it isn't timely enough, you could get married in one state, then in another, and then the central database would have a conflict.  Or you might be unable to get remarried on the day that your divorce is finalized, because the state takes three weeks to submit that paperwork.

Plus, even the firearm database, which has a clear public safety purpose (regardless of whether it *achieves* that purpose), has its opponents.  So does [the TSA No-Fly list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Fly_List#False_positives).

---

From another angle, (at least in the US) there's no group who would really want to advocate for such a thing *en masse*.  Democrats/Liberals tend to be for government oversight, but against interfering with people's personal lives.  Republicans/Conservatives tend to be for smaller government, but against letting people do "immoral" things.

---

Finally, why should a government agency maintain a database like this without it being illegal?  No government is going to want to spend money to prevent something legal from happening, without making it illegal first.  And if whoever dictates that this database should be used has the power to set this restriction into it without making it officially illegal, then it's still *practically* illegal or the database is broken.

---

#### TL;DR

Thus the only thing the government can *practically* do is make it illegal, and punish anyone who is caught.  Trying to make it technically infeasible runs into the same host of problems that current government databases have, and there's no point in creating such a database restriction for something that isn't a crime.

Comment: I think marital database is far simpler than mental health database. Either you're married or not. Mental health is very nuance. People used to think homosexuality as a mental disorder.

Comment: 3 weeks paper works? Hello? One google sheet is enough and that syncs in minutes

Comment: My marriage status is listed on my ID card and I live in Indonesia. Like government doesn't know who is married or not? I mean it's kind of easy to know if the act of marrying requires government approval

Comment: @user4951 - Mental health is very nuanced, but the specific circumstances that can put you in that database are very clear: You're either involuntarily committed, or a court declares you mentally incompetent.  It's trivial to answer those questions about any one person.

Comment: @user4951 - Also, you didn't specify the country, so I assumed the USA, which is a federal system. Marriage is under state law, so there's 50 different sets of rules.  So the state may know, but not the federal government, or vice versa.  In other countries, it's certainly more feasible to have a single database to hold this information, if there's only one central authority issuing marriage licenses (or the equivalent).  That said, see my updates.

Comment: Might be worth adding that many countries respect marriages from other countries as well; that means it's not _just_ your country being slow with its paperwork. There's still an issue if you're married in your home country and another country, and you're going to need the whole world to agree on keeping this list. _Even_ the countries where polygamy is legal (see the issue there?)

Comment: @user4951 In Indonesia then it would, perhaps, be possible. But in countries like the US or UK, which do not have compulsory ID cards and which shy away from them and from consolidated government records, this would be impractical.

Comment: If I am married in Indonesia, if I go to US and get married again, will I be guilty of polygamy or US will simply not recoqnize my Indonesian's marriage?

Comment: @user4951 that would be considered polygamy, yes.

Comment: @user4951 Guilty? Yes. Likely for either country to actually care? Ask [Law.SE]